# Rails - add a check box to form and check if it's checked on post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I have a common problem: I am using devise and I want to add a checkbox for "terms and conditions".

It's well covered everywhere, except for one moment. If I do

```
<%= f.check_box(:terms_and_conditions )%>
```

Then I get an error that :terms_and_conditions is not defined. Where should I define it? The model? The controller?

Comment: You should define it as `model attribute` or `virtual attribute`.

Comment: if its not a column of table the add as a 'attr_accessor'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`acceptance`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#acceptance) validation method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :terms_and_conditions, acceptance: true
end
```

As stated in the Rails Guide

> This validation is very specific to web applications and this 'acceptance' does not need to be recorded anywhere in your database (if you don't have a field for it, the helper will just create a virtual attribute).

In addition, you'll need to add the `:terms_and_conditions` parameter to the permitted parameters for sign up:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base  
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :terms_and_conditions
  end
end
```

Comment: And how do I put it in the view? f.checkbox(:acceptance)?

Comment: Nope, just keep your view exactly the way you have it, and simply add the `:terms_and_conditions, acceptance: true` line to your user model.

Comment: But how will it understand that it's related to :terms_and_conditions if it's not mentioned anywhere?

Comment: I'm confused by your question... What are both "it"s in your question referring to?

Comment: I mean if terms_and_conditions is undeclared the method is still missing. Or is it? How does the framework tie the undeclared parameter to acceptance and to the checkbox?

Comment: As it says in the quote I posted, `the helper will just create a virtual attribute`, meaning that the `:terms_and_conditions` attribute is declared in the model by the validation line. The update I just made to my answer will allow the `:terms_and_conditions` parameter to be passed to the `DeviseController`.

Comment: in the view you shoul add: <%= f.check_box :terms_and_conditions %>

Comment: 'for' is deprecated, here is an update https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise-pundit/issues/33